# How do I back up my apps?

Tags: backup, chromebook

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 on my Acer C720 Chromebook, and I am planning on upgrading my undersized drive that is not optimal for running full Linux, and reinstalling Chrome OS and a Linux distribution. I am going switch to either Ubuntu GNOME or Fedora, and I wanted to know what to back up to my SD card so I can retain all my applications I have installed. I am definitely backing up home, but I presume that when I put replace that directory in my newly installed OS, I won't have all my apps back. I am relatively new to Linux, so you might have to spell some things out to me. Thank you.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages Also if you have installed any PPAs you may want to make a list of them, but not automatically restore as if a new version of Ubuntu the ppa may not work and then create issues. If same version, it should be ok. And in addition to /home, if you made any systemwide settings for grub, Internet or other you may want to backup those settings from /etc. IF not Ubuntu then you cannot restore easily, as Other Linux use different tools than apt.

Comment: It will be the same version, so how do you automatically restore?

Comment: Link above has both save and reinstall instructions use dpkg.